# JASidePanelController load instance of ViewController

Tags: ios, cocoa, uinavigationcontroller, sidebar

I'm using JASidePanels for my iOS app, and I've run into an issue. (https://github.com/gotosleep/JASidePanels)

I use storyboards, so I will try to explain how the situation looks right now (WITHOUT JASidePanel):

My root VC is VC1. VC1 contains a login panel which brings you to Navigation Viewcontroller1 (NVC1) with a segue. This NVC1 has VC2 as it's main ViewController. VC2 contains a table view with a list of names. I LOAD these names in VC1, create an instance of VC2, and send the data there. This works.

Now I'm trying to add JASidePanels. The problem I'm experiencing now, is that the table view with names doesn't show up, I only get a blank VC2 view, but the side panels both seem to work. The setup I used for this is as followed:

Root VC is still VC1. After logging in, a segue brings you to MySidePanelController, which is a subclass of JASidePanelController. MySidePanelController is created in Storyboard and has the class MySidePanelController. I have created 2 new ViewControllers with Storyboard ID's leftViewController and rightViewController. Also, I set the Storyboard ID of my Navigation ViewController to centerViewController.
In the MySidePanelController.m class, I added the following code:

```
-(void) awakeFromNib
{
    [self setLeftPanel:[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"leftViewController"]];
    [self setCenterPanel:[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"centerViewController"]];
    [self setRightPanel:[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"rightViewController"]];
}
```

My debug panel also indicates that ViewController2 is loaded twice, which I don't understand. I think the problem is that the instance of VC2 I created in VC1 isn't loaded, but instead an empty VC2 from the storyboard is called. **How would I set the 'setCenterPanel' to the instance of VC2 I created in VC1?**

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If VC2 is created via VC1 for your data push, then created again via storyboard, that'd give you two instances. Remove it from the awakeFromNib method since VC2 has already been created. Set it to a variable and assign it to the .centerPanel in a separate method.

Comment: Ok cool, so how would I do that? I'll set VC2 to .centerPanel in the viewDidLoad of MySidePanelController then, but do I need to make some kind of global/public UIViewController variable to communicate the VC2 from VC1 to MySidePanelController then?

Comment: If you're going to be pushing data to it, you'll need some communication. It really depends on the data you are trying to push. I'd just use a global variable.

Comment: Awesome it works, thanks a lot man! I've now created a DataClass that will manage the data I'm communicating between the views :)

Comment: can you share some sample code because i also facing same problem and i also remove awakeFromNib method as i doing this way `- (IBAction)loginServiceCall:(id)sender {
    profileViewController *profile = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"profile"];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:profile animated:YES];
}` profileView is subclass of jasidepanels and i got this [result](http://screencast.com/t/ZxXkoy6Q) ,all storyborad data hidden and not show properly.